# New using React: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in React and I following a tutorial and I'm getting an error and I haven't been able to figure it out. I'm trying to get some data from an API to display it in my project.

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PhotoList from './PhotoList';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
      this.state = {
        photos: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {  
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
      .then((response) => {return response.json()})
      .then((photos) => {this.setState({ photos: photos })})
  }
  render() {  
    if (this.state.photos.length > 0) {
      return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <PhotoList listado={this.state.photos} />
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return <span>Esperando photos</span>
    }
  }
}

export default App;





import React from 'react';
import Photo from './Photo';

const PhotoList = ({ Photos  }) => { 
    return (
        <div>   
            {
                Photos.map((Photos, i) => {    
                    return (
                        <div>                        
                            key={i}
                            id={Photos[i].id} 
                            title={Photos[i].title} 
                            url={Photos[i].url} 
                        </div>                          
                    );
                })
            }
        </div>
    );

}




export default PhotoList;
```

I'm getting this error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59VBH.png)

Thank you so much in advance,

Comment: The list of photos is passed in as `listado`.

Comment: ^^ .. not `Photos`. So in `PhotoList`, you want `({listado}) =>` not `({Photos}) =>`. **Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future.**

Comment: Unrelated, but in the future, please post your error as formatted text, not as an image.

Comment: Side note: Within your `map` call, your `Photos` parameter is an individual photo, not the array. Also, your attributes should be *within* the `<div>` start tag, not text within the div itself. So suppose we change that to `listado`, it should look like this: `listado.map((photo, i) => <div key={i} id={photo.id} title={photo.title} url={photo.url} />)` (Separately: Note that `url` is not a valid attribute for `div` elements.)

Comment: Would you in-line paste the error image here? The image seems to be gone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things to point out.

*You can follow along* on
[image: Edit mornl2n9yy]

### 1. Prop name passed to `PhotoList` do not match.

Within `App`, you pass photos to PhotoList using `listado` property.

```js
<PhotoList listado={this.state.photos} />
```

But you are trying to retrieve non-existing `Photos` property.

```js
const PhotoList = ({ Photos  }) => {
```

So either you should change property name to `Photos` (lowercase preferred)

```js
<PhotoList Photos={this.state.photos} />
```

**or** change the declaration of `PhotoList`

```js
const PhotoList = ({ listado }) => {
```

### 2. Conflict with callback argument name

```js
Photos.map((Photos, i) => {
```

Should be

```js
Photos.map((photo, i) => {
```

Or any other ID other than `Photos`.

### 3. No need to access an element within `.map` using an array index

Instead of,

```js
Photos.map((Photos, i) => {    
    return (
        <div>                        
            key={i}
            id={Photos[i].id} 
            title={Photos[i].title} 
            url={Photos[i].url} 
        </div>                          
    );
})
```

You should

```js
photos.map((photo, i) => {
    return (
    <div>
        <p>key={i}</p>
        <p>id={photo.id}</p>
        <p>title={photo.title}</p>
        <p>url={photo.url}</p>
        </div>
    );
})
```

You can see that `photo` is an individual photo object thus no need to access it with `Photos[i]`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it was very helpful to solve the problem